# How to support internationalization & SEO

Tags: html, internationalization, seo, facelets, meta-tags

I have looked over a few similar questions here at stackoverflow and I can't seem to locate a clear cut answer.

I know how to internationalize my page content, but how do I notify crawlers for SEO?

Specifically, lets say I have a pages that describes content in Norwegian and english. 
Must I use multiple tags with relation to the meta "description" tag?

Also, I presume that it is good enough to add various languages to a single "keywords" meta tag as follows: 
<`meta name="keywords" content="thejarbar.org, thejartender Java, Windows, Ubuntu, Linux, Virtualbox, tutorials, examples, guides, lærer, eksempler" />` ?

Comment: Does one single page feature multiple languages? In XHTML, you can always adorn an element with the `xml:lang` attribute, you could add that to your meta elements, and definitely to the text blocks.

Comment: Not exactly as I am using facelets with internationalization. So the page is translated into 2 languages based on locale settings, but I won't implement the norwegian version of my site if I can't let crawlers find it.

Comment: So then can't you just put the appropriate meta data into each page separately?

Comment: The pages are generated Dynamically. The actual text within the #body as well as all other things like alt attributes, title attributes and such are also generated synamically by a process/phase.What the client gets is a rendered page from the server in the language most relevant out of (en) and (no). The problem is that I am unaware if the <meta> tags support this. I have further read that multiple meta tags of the same "name" can be penalised by crawlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use it like this:

```
<meta name="keywords" lang="en" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
<meta name="keywords" lang="no" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3">
```

But I feel better with different URL for different languages and then generating a language specific meta-data.

Comment: thank you. I also note your preferred methodology, but as I am using Facelets + templates, I gonna use your solution as I can pass the set of meta tags for each page.